# Remove multiple list elements knowing their indices in python

Tags: python, list

What is the best and most pythonic way to delete items from a list knowing only the items indices?

```
my_list = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
my_removal_indices = [0, 2, 4]
# what to do
my_list = ['one', 'three']
```

Please note that something like:

```
my_list = [item for item in my_list if my_list.index(item) in my_removal_indices]
```

does not work, as the elements in `my_list` may not be unique.
Also, of course, when just iterating, the indices for `my_list` change.
Is there a nicer way than e.g. creating a new, empty list and storing all wanted items there and setting it as `my_list` afterwards?

Thanks!

Comment: The answers with `enumerate` are probably what you want. But since you said _"Is there a nicer way than e.g. creating a new, empty list and storing all wanted items there and setting it as mylist afterwards"_ - well that is essentially what those answers are doing. Depending on your use case, and I doubt it is necessary, but you could do this with a linked list instead of a regular list to avoid recreating the whole list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to iterate through your list, with corresponding indices. Then check those indices against your removal list.

```
>>> [val for idx, val in enumerate(my_list) if idx not in my_removal_indices]
['one', 'three']
```

If the index list was long, for performance could also switch to a `set` to speed up the `in` check

```
my_removal_indices = {0, 2, 4}
>>> [val for idx, val in enumerate(my_list) if idx not in my_removal_indices]
['one', 'three']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
my_list = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
my_removal_indices = [0, 2, 4]
print([my_list[i] for i in range(len(my_list)) if i not in my_removal_indices])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in place as opposed to creating a new list with a comprehension, you *can* mutate the list by deleting the elements so long as you start from the back of the list:

```
my_list = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

my_removal_indices = [0, 2, 4]

for i in sorted(my_removal_indices,reverse=True):
    del my_list[i]

print(my_list)
# ['one', 'three']
```